Editing System Workflow Templates - "Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved"
Setting CiviCRM up for the first time, and trying to configure our receipts (system workflow message). Just want to add in a few extra tokens (like contact ID as our membership number).
Any changes, even adding a space, gets an error message - "Error
Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved"
I've searched through old questions and followed the advice. Added new permissions, allocate CiviCRM admin role to WP admins too.
Using 5.71.2 (I'll upgrade when I'm more confident about not losing anything) on WordPress. No obvious competing plug-ins.
Any ideas?

Can you turn on Wordpress debug to find more details about the error?

How are you updating the templates? Are you doing it from within a draft bulk mailing or from the Administer - CiviMail - Message Templates screen? Or also are you using the message admin extension - if so try turning that off. Also separately I don't recommend using contact id as the membership id, since when you merge duplicate contacts their membership id might change!

Seems it was a Wordfence protection message. When I turned off the Message Admin extension, and repeated the action, it showed the full error message / allowed me to whitelist the action. Thanks Demerit.

could you pls add that as an Answer so it is more prominent - or do you need more 'reputation' first?

Seems it was a Wordfence protection message. When I turned off the Message Admin extension, and repeated the action, it showed the full error message / allowed me to whitelist the action. Thanks Demerit.
